# Tomcat 404 Handler

Tags: http-status-code-404, tomcat7, servlets

I need to add a 404 handler servlet to tomcat to catch 404 exceptions (not found). This is easy. But no matter what I do, I cannot find out what URL was passed to tomcat to cause the 404 in the first place (URL + query string, if any).

Anyone have some experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve) to log the requests to that specific host.

There are several ways to do this, depending on whether you have virtual hosts or not, or if you prefer to add specific configuration under `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[engine_name]/[host_name]` or directly in your `server.xml`.

For most GNU/Linux distributions, and assuming `tomcat7`, the default (i.e. using Catalina engine and localhost host) this is `/etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost`. Adapt it to your tomcat version, engine and virtual host (and operating system, you don't specify one so I've assumed a GNU/Linux):

```
<Host name="localhost" ...>
   ...
   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
     prefix="localhost_access." suffix=".log"
     pattern="common"/>
   ...
 </Host>
```

Comment: Your suggestion works for creating a log entry for the faulty URL. The question is how to get the URL in the 404 servlet.